# When will statistical significance be achieved

Tags: statistics

Lets imagine that a person can predict if a coin will show head or tail when thrown.

Given she is 70 percent of times correct how many predictions does she have to make until it is statistically proven that something strange is going on?

Given she is 60 percent of times correct with her predictions how many predictions she have to make to achieve statistical significance?

Comment: What is the required significance level?

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need a percentage. E.g. you want to be 95% sure or 99.97% sure that your statement is correct. (The significance level)

Then you can test the hypothesis, e.g.: http://statistics.about.com/od/Inferential-Statistics/a/An-Example-Of-A-Hypothesis-Test.htm

Where you need to test prediction n out of N correct with 70%/60% correct against null hypothesis of 50%.

Better example: http://20bits.com/article/hypothesis-testing-the-basics

Answer (score 0):

Important points:

1. It depends on your test of statistical significance
2. You will only be able to find a probability that she produces a statistical significant result, known as the [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power)
3. Even if she is only correct on average $50\%$ of times, there is still a probability that she will produce a statistically significant result (if such a thing is possible)

Suppose for example your definition of statistical significance is a result which has a two-sided probability less than $5\%$ of being that extreme or more if she is choosing at random.  Then you could use the following R code to find the probabilities of a statistically significant result

```
power <- function(statsig, actualprob, n){ 
    bottom <- qbinom(statsig/2 , n, 1/2) - 1
    pbinom(bottom, n, actualprob) + 1 - pbinom(n - bottom - 1, n, actualprob)}
statsig     <- 0.05 
samplesizes <- 1:20
results <- cbind( power(statsig, 50/100, samplesizes ), 
                  power(statsig, 60/100, samplesizes ), 
                  power(statsig, 70/100, samplesizes ) ) 
colnames(results) <- c("50%", "60%", "70%")
```

which would give

```
> results

             50%        60%        70%
 [1,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [2,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [3,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [4,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [5,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [6,] 0.03125000 0.05075200 0.11837800
 [7,] 0.01562500 0.02963200 0.08257300
 [8,] 0.00781250 0.01745152 0.05771362
 [9,] 0.03906250 0.07434496 0.19643626
[10,] 0.02148438 0.04803512 0.14945203
[11,] 0.01171875 0.03096709 0.11303734
[12,] 0.03857422 0.08625351 0.25302172
[13,] 0.02246094 0.05921774 0.20255096
[14,] 0.01293945 0.04040026 0.16086106
[15,] 0.03515625 0.09242967 0.29695959
[16,] 0.02127075 0.06608519 0.24588947
[17,] 0.04904175 0.12852049 0.38879291
[18,] 0.03088379 0.09544803 0.33269435
[19,] 0.01921082 0.07025436 0.28223844
[20,] 0.04138947 0.12721050 0.41641377
```

and you can see that the probabilities are not monotonic, though they tend to increase.  Change `samplesizes` to see larger sample sizes.

If for example you wanted a $95\%$ chance of getting a statistically significant result, then when she has a $70\%$ chance of predicting correctly you need a sample size of $79, 81, 83, 84$ or of $86$ or more,  while when she has a $60\%$ chance of predicting correctly you need a sample size of $327, 329, 331 $ or of $333$ or more.

These numbers are rather higher than I might have guessed. Remember that you still have an almost $5\%$ chance of getting a statistically significant result even if she is just predicting at random, even for very large sample sizes.